# How to arrange columns in my Admin bar in WordPress dashboard?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I am using the below code in my `functions.php` to show a 60x60 image thumbnail of each posts featured image on WordPress dashboard but it shows up in like the 3rd column and I would like it to show up first to the left of the title column - can't seem to make that work - any suggestions anyone?

```
// show featured images in dashboard
add_image_size( 'showimg-admin-post-featured-image', 60, 60, false );

// Add the posts and pages columns filter. both use the same function.
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'showimg_add_post_admin_thumbnail_column', 2);
add_filter('manage_pages_columns', 'showimg_add_post_admin_thumbnail_column', 2);

// Add the featured image column
function showimg_add_post_admin_thumbnail_column($showimg_columns){
    $showimg_columns['showimg_thumb'] = __('Featured Image');
    return $showimg_columns;
}

// Manage Post and Page Admin Panel Columns
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'showimg_show_post_thumbnail_column', 5, 2);
add_action('manage_pages_custom_column', 'showimg_show_post_thumbnail_column', 5, 2);

// Get featured-thumbnail size post thumbnail and display it
function showimg_show_post_thumbnail_column($showimg_columns, $showimg_id){
    switch($showimg_columns){
        case 'showimg_thumb':
        if( function_exists('the_post_thumbnail') ) {
            echo the_post_thumbnail( 'showimg-admin-post-featured-image' );
        }
        else
            echo 'hmm… your theme doesn\'t support featured image…';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Reordering columns is illustrated here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8427/change-order-of-custom-columns-for-edit-panels you need to update `showimg_add_post_admin_thumbnail_column` with all of the columns in the order you want them.  Or you can array splice your column after the checkbox.

Comment: @Howard E Would you care to illustrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert the item to the right of the checkbox (index 0) in the array.

Use `array_merge` and `array_slice` to add to the column array.

```
// Add the featured image column
function showimg_add_post_admin_thumbnail_column($showimg_columns){
    $new_column['showimg_thumb'] = __('Featured Image');
    return array_merge(
        array_slice( $showimg_columns, 0, 1, true ),
        $new_column,
        array_slice( $showimg_columns, 1, null, true )
    );
}
```

For reference... the default Column Order Array is this:

```
array(
    'cb'         => '<input type="checkbox" />',
    'title'      => "Title",
    'author'     => "Author",
    'categories' => "Categories",
    'tags'       => "Tags",
    'comments'   => '<span class="vers comment-grey-bubble" title="Comments"><span class="screen-reader-text">Comments</span></span>',
    'date'       => "Date"
);
```